# Tweepy always returns details for only one user

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, flask, tweepy

So, below is the code I used for twitter oAuth using flask and tweepy.. It was well and good when I tested it for the first time but later on, I discovered irrespective of the browsers or computers it always returns my own tweets only, even when I am completely signed out of the twitter.... I don't store it in any session or database...

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, render_template, flash
import tweepy
import flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
consumer_key = app.config["CONSUMER_ID"]
consumer_secret = app.config["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
access_token_key = app.config["ACCESS_KEY"]
access_token_secret = app.config["ACCESS_SECRET"]

@app.route('/')
def send_token():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return flask.render_template('tweets.html', tweets=api.user_timeline())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not passing any arguments into `user_timeline()` it's likely that it defaults to your account since your twitter account is the account the API keys are linked to. If you want to get other users tweets a simple way to do that would be:

```
@app.route('/<user_name>')
def user_tweets(user_name):
    api = get_twitter_api()
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user_name, count=200)
    return flask.render_template('tweets.html', tweets=tweets)
```